# Paperclip content_type validation error only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, paperclip-validation

Paperclip's content_type validation is behaving differently in my development environment and production environment, and I have no idea what might be causing this difference.

I have a model with a paperclip attachment. It has this validation:
`validates_attachment_content_type :upload, content_type: /\Aaudio/`

When adding an mp3 through a form, it succeeds in development, but fails in production with this error: "Upload has contents that are not what they are reported to be"

It's the same file and same browser. *Something* is causing this difference. Anyone have ideas of what to investigate?

**Update**
I replaced the validations with `do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :upload`

When I upload an mp3, I still get this error: "Upload has contents that are not what they are reported to be"

If I strip the file extension off, the file can be uploaded without error. Adding the extension back on when a user downloads it is a possible solution, but feels incredibly hacky. I'm otherwise out of guesses as to how to fix this.

Comment: What is your OS environment? This error is likely going to be caused by the [`file` command](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file). If you're using Windows, you need to [make sure you have `file`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) on your system & in your PATH

Comment: @richard Is there any solution for this? My development machine is linux mint. It is okay in development mode. But I got error message in production. my content type is 'audio/mp3', 'audio/mpeg'

Comment: There should be a solution - it's all about how the OS sees the file. Can you make a question and show me the log for that particular request? I'll write an answer for you

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? am getting the same error...